# Using html modal windows in ZK

Tags: html, zk

I am trying to create a html modal window in zk. But the hide functionality hides also the window as shown i the image [image: Modal window hidden]

Code snippet:

```
<tabpanel id="borgerdkRequestPanel2">
    <div>
        <html xmlns="native" xmlns:u="zul"
            xmlns:zk="zk">
            <a data-target="#myModal1" role="button"
                class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
                Launch demo modal
            </a>
            <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide "
                tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="false">
                        ×
                    </button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel1">
                        Modal header
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body…</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn"
                        data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </html>
    </div>
</tabpanel>
```

It seems to be some kind of zk problem, as the code runs fine in html. CSS is bootstrap. And ZK framework is 7.0.3.

Comment: I can't get your code snippet working in zk fiddle, is it possible to make a working code snippet there?

Answer (score 0):

remove `hide` class from your modal. If you want some animation add instead `fade` class to your modal.

The result should be this:

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
```

Tested on ZK 7.0.4